# What's different in San Juan's second edition?

Tags: edition-comparison, san-juan

I just bought a copy of San Juan after playing it a few times on iPad and loving it. When I got it home, I saw that it is the second edition. On Board Game Geek, first and second editions have their own entries. **What's new/different in San Juan's second edition** that it would get classified as a separate game?

Comment: @PatLudwig Why was the [version] tag removed? The tag description says it's for "Questions about different versions of the same game", which is exactly what this question is.

Comment: @Thunderforge Could version work if it was the only tag on a question?  Will anyone ever use it as a way to group questions together that they want to see?  It adds no value.

Comment: [Meta discussion about the version tag](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1563/3389).

Answer (score 2):

Artwork and the following.

The Prefecture now costs 4 instead of 3.
With the Goldmine, you now get to keep the cheapest card instead of any card.
With the Guildhall, you get 1 point per production building and 1 point for each different production building.
New building Hut: "In the trader phase, the owner of a hut draws one card from the supply if no good was sold by any player during this phase." 
The Bank now costs 3 instead of 4.

And yes this is a copy paste from BGG, if you don't want that please explain how BGG didn't fully explain this.

Link: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1330934/differences-between-1ed-and-2ed

Comment: If you're going to copy/paste, you should link to source.

Answer (score -2):

San Juan Second Edition has full-colour cards and the addition of the Cathedral card